# count non-NA values and group by variable

Tags: r, count, aggregate, na

I am trying to show how many complete observations there are per variabie `ID`  *without*  using the `complete.cases` package or any other package.

If I use `na.omit` to filter out the NA values, I will lose all of the IDs which might have ZERO complete cases.

In the end, I'd like a frequency table with two columns: `ID` and `Number of Complete Observations`

```
> length(unique(data$ID))
[1] 332

> head(data)
  ID value
1  1   NA
2  1   NA
3  1   NA
4  1   NA
5  1   NA
6  1   NA

> dim(data)
[1] 772087      2
```

When I try to create my own function `z` - which counts non-NA values and apply that in the `aggregate()` function, the IDs with zero complete observations are left out.  I should be left with 332 rows, not 323.  How does one resolve this using base functions?

```
z <- function(x){
  sum(!is.na(x))
}

aggregate(value ~ ID, data = data , FUN = "z")

> nrow(aggregate(isna ~ ID, data = data , FUN = "z"))
[1] 323
```

Comment: Could you dput() your data?

Comment: Not a nice solution, but you can set all the NA values equal to a number (e.g. 0 or 9999999) which is not present in your `value` variable. Count the number of observations without that number in its row. And then set all those numbers back to NA.

Comment: `complete.cases` is a function not a package

Comment: See the "na.action" argument of `aggregate` -- "na.action = NULL". Or, for this case, you could use `table` like `table(!is.na(data$value), data$ID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to do this is using `table`:

```
df2 <- table(df$Id, !is.na(df$value))[,2]
data.frame(ID = names(df2), value = df2)
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(Id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), value = c(NA, 
1, 1, 2, 2, NA, 3, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4)), .Names = c("Id", "value"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Base `R` you can use your utility function like this:

```
stack(by(data$value, data$ID, FUN=function(x) sum(!is.na(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly use table for this purpose. Below is the sample code:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), value = c(2, 
1, 1, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4)), .Names = c("Id", "value"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")


df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(with(df1, table(Id, value)))
resultDf <- data.frame(Id=row.names(df2), count=apply(df2, 1, sum)) 
resultDf
```

The code makes a table of id and value. Then it just sums the non-na values from the table. Hope this is easy to understand and helps.